# How can I write a Python code which will serve a .html file on 0.0.0.0?

Tags: python, http, server

By this command:

```
$ python -m http.server <port>
```

Works properly. By writing:

```
#Python 3.7.3
import http.server
import socketserver
import random

PORT = random.randint(1000, 65535)
handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT),handler)

print("serving at port", PORT)
link = ("http://0.0.0.0:{}").format(PORT)
print(link)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

I can do it too. But the both code serves any file named 'index.html' from that directory. So how can I serve a specific .html file using Python ? Please help me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the simplest way of serving a html file on localhost is to use [flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

HTML hardcode, not recommended:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return '<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug = True)
```

Instead of returning hardcode HTML from the function, a HTML file can be rendered by the render_template() function:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template(‘hello.html’)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug = True)
```

Detailed tutorial can be find here:
[Flask templates tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_templates.htm)